# Para que serve um submodule no git?

Tags: git

Certo dia fui clonar uma biblioteca no `github` e lá tinha uma instrução para utilizarmos o comando `git submodule update`.

Trabalho há algum tempo com o `git` e até então não tinha conhecimento desse comando.

Para que serve esse comando `submodule`?

Answer (score 7):

Este comando é útil quando você quer inserir um outro repositório git dentro do seu projeto principal (uma biblioteca, por exemplo).

Para o git o submodulo será um projeto totalmente independente. Você pode editar o conteúdo abaixo da pasta do submódulo, comitar, fazer push, etc. Desde que tenha permissão para isso :)

Existem alternativas, como gerenciadores de pacote, que organizam as dependências de outras formas mais eficientes e seguras.

Comment: Nesse último parágrafo, então teríamos como exemplo o `composer`, `npm` e o `gem`.

Comment: Exatamente! Esses gerenciadores geralmente analisam as dependências do projeto, baixam os arquivos em uma pasta específica e esta fica fora do controle de versões do git no seu projeto (.gitignore). Em geral você pode atualizar tudo com uma simples linha de comando.

Gosto de usar submodulos quando também estou fazendo modificações no próprio submodulo também. Caso contrário, não recomendo.

Answer (score 4):

*Submodule* serve para você gerenciar os módulos do seu repositório!

**O que isso quer dizer?!**

Digamos que você está criando um programa e precisa adicionar uma biblioteca que você encontrou no github para facilitar o desenvolvimento. Você pode adicionar essa biblioteca como um sub módulo da sua aplicação.

**Qual a vantagem de usar isso ao invés de somente copiar o código?**

Se você simplesmente copiar o código:

- Pode ter problemas com a licença do código que está utilizando
- Perde o histórico da biblioteca que está usando
- Se houver alguma mudança no código da biblioteca você não saberá disso a menos que fique copiando constantemente o código

Se você usar o *submodule*:

- Se houver uma atualização na biblioteca você poderá facilmente atualizá-la
- Provavelmente não terá problema com licenciamento de código
- Diminui o tamanho do seu repositório

**Como o *submodule* funciona na prática?**

De maneira simplificada pode-se dizer que ele mantém um ponteiro para o repositório

Para mais detalhes veja https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: Só faltou dizer que um gerenciador de pacotes (npm, composer, etc) é ainda mais simples/vantajoso que um submodule

Comment: Sim! Mas nem todas as linguagens têm gerenciadores de pacotes, por exemplo linguagem C (pelo menos eu desconheço um)

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, o comando [`git submodule update`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) diz ao Git que você deseja que seus submódulos façam check-out do commit já especificado no índice do superprojeto. Se você deseja *atualizar* seus submódulos para a confirmação mais recente disponível a partir do controle remoto, será necessário fazer isso diretamente nos submódulos.
Resuminto:

```
# Get the submodule initially
git submodule add ssh://bla submodule_dir
git submodule init

# Time passes, submodule upstream is updated
# and you now want to update

# Change to the submodule directory
cd submodule_dir

# Checkout desired branch
git checkout master

# Update
git pull

# Get back to your project root
cd ..

# Now the submodules are in the state you want, so
git commit -am "Pulled down update to submodule_dir"
```

No caso se você for preguiçoso ( kkk )

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```