# Como criar e manter um repositório separado para a subpasta de outro repositório?

Tags: git, repository

Atualmente, tenho um repositório git com várias pastas, por exemplo:

```
/pasta1
    /pasta1/subpasta1-1
    /pasta1/subpasta1-2
/pasta2
    /pasta2/subpasta2-1
    /pasta2/subpasta2-2
/pasta3
    /pasta3/subpasta3-1
    /pasta3/subpasta3-2
```

Quero tornar `/pasta2/subpasta2-1` em um repositório separado, porque quero fazer push e compartilhar esse código como uma funcionalidade independente. Contudo, quero manter essa pasta como parte do repositório principal, porque seu desenvolvimento acontece acompanhando passo a passo o da aplicação inteira do qual ele faz parte.

Como posso fazer isso usando **git**?

Comment: git branching ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar os submódulos do Git, onde o Git gerencia repositórios dentro de repositórios.

Existe uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111313/para-que-serve-um-submodule-no-git) aqui no SO que você pode saber mais sobre a funcionalidade.

Comment: Obrigado! Segui os seguintes passos:

1. Copiei `subpasta2-1` para um novo diretório e a inicializei como um repositório git indepentente;
2. Removi `subpasta2-1` do meu repositório original;
3. Executei `git submodule add <novo_repositório_de_subpasta2-1> pasta2/subpasta2-1`