# Github sub-pasta linkar para outro repositorio

Tags: git, github

Tenho um repositório de livros gratuitos de programação, e eles ta ficando muito pesado e fica difícil para qualquer pessoa clonar e subir qualquer coisa, então queria fazer igual o repositório do dracula do zeno rocha (https://github.com/dracula/dracula-theme), varias pastas que linka para outro repositório especifico do que a pessoa quer, por exemplo, alguém quer subir um livro na pasta de algoritmos, ele entra na pasta de algorimo e clona o repositório que só tem os livros de algoritmo, mas não sei como fazer subpastas linkaveis a outros repôs, meu repositório https://github.com/danrigoni/free-livros

Comment: Relacionado: [Para que serve um submodule no git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111313/3774)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que este repositório faz é "linkar" outros repositórios usando "submodules". O comando para fazer isso no git é `git submodule add <git@github ...>` e deve ser executado na raiz no seu repositório.

Para adicionar um sub módulo em outro lugar, indique o caminho após o repositório: `git submodule add <git@github ...> algoritmos/`

Entretanto, para isso funcionar, cada uma dessas seções seria um repositório diferente e vc teria um repositório para fazer essa agregação.